# Do not add hash to the URL after $location.hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some of my form pages are pretty tall. I've written a function to scroll to the first error on the form after hitting Save button like this

```
vm.scrollToError = function() {
    var anchor;

    for (var prop in vm.InwardLeaseForm.$error) {
        anchor = vm.InwardLeaseForm.$error[prop][0].$name;
        break;
    }

    $location.hash(anchor);
    $anchorScroll.yOffset = 300;
    $anchorScroll(anchor);
};
```

My problem is, this adds a hash with an id of the field to the URL. Is there a way to do this but not add this extra `#vm.InwardLeaseForm_integerField_contractTerm_2` in this case to the URL?

Comment: Use sessionStorage

Comment: Remove `$location.hash(anchor);` …?

Comment: Not sure I understand why I'd have to use sessionStorage for this.

Comment: @CBroe, Oh well... I thought this is necessary for the $anchorScroll to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, this adds a hash with an id of the field to the URL.

Well, that’s what `$location.hash(anchor);` does. So remove it, if you don’t want it to happen …

> I thought this is necessary for the $anchorScroll to work.

Reading documentation helps ;-) - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll:

> When called, it scrolls to the element related to the specified `hash` or (if omitted) to the current value of $location.hash()

So, this only falls back onto the current location hash value, if you don’t explicitly specify what element to scroll to - but since you are using `$anchorScroll(anchor);`, modifying the location hash prior to this isn’t even necessary here.